# Realize the server side's judgment that the client has successfully received the response sent by the service

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have a business in the following scenario: the client makes a request to me, and I have some requests that take a long time to process. After I return the response, the client has already handled this business as a timeout. Is there any way for Java or spring-boot to realize the server side's judgment that the client has successfully received the response sent by the service

Comment: Wait, so the client already timed out. But you still want to send the response?

Comment: What kind of client--HTTP, socket, messaging? This is exactly what 202 Accepted is for.

Comment: The server returns response, but the client determines that the timeout has occurred and no response has been processed, resulting in inconsistency between the server and the client's business database log

Comment: It's client--HTTP message